# Excel Formula issue

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've been trying to write a formula to help me with rostering. It seems to work if I put the first few parts in, but after that it says "The formula you typed contains an error."

Can anyone see the error? I've been staring at for hours now and I can't figure it out!

=IF(C5="1000-1800",7.5,IF(C5="1000-1830",8,IF(C5="1000-1900",8.5,IF(C5="1100-1900",7.5,IF(C5="1100-1930",8,IF(C5="1100-2000",8.5,IF(C5="1200-2000",7.5,IF(C5="1200-2030",8,IF(C5="1200-2100",8.5,IF(C5="1300-2100",7.5,IF(C5="1300-2130",7.5,IF(C5="1300-2130",8,IF(C5="1300-2200",8.5,IF(C5="1400-2200",7.5,IF(C5="1400-2230",8,IF(C5="1400-2300",8.5,IF(C5="1400-2330",9,IF(C5="1400-0000",8.5,IF(C5="1500-0000",7.5,IF(C5="1500-0100",8.5,IF(C5="1500-0200",10.5,IF(C5="1600-0200",9.5,IF(C5="1700-0200",8.5,IF(C5="1800-
0200",7.5,IF(C5="1900-0200",6.5))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Comment: Just a suggestion but you should probably go about this a different way... Set up a table using the values you listed then use a vlookup or match / index formula.  Long formulas like this should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: It works in excel 2010 if you take Steven's advice and remove 9 close parentheses

Comment: Your formula seems to calculate the difference in hours minus 0.5. I suggest you use Excel to calculate it. Something like: `=INT(RIGHT(C5,4))-INT(LEFT(C5;4))-0.5`. To work with times past midnight, add 24 and do `MOD(...;24)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula has 25 open parentheses and 34 close parentheses.

However, I agree with the suggestion to simplify with VLOOKUP or MATCH/INDEX.

Answer (score 1):

The max Nested IFs can be up to 7 (at least in Excel 2003)

Answer (score 0):

Create a Lookup table in, say columns **F** and **G**, then use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C5,F1:G25,2,FALSE)
```

[image]